# No hyphenation of a word in square brackets

Tags: hyphenation, brackets

I'm having square brackets in normal text. Unfortunately latex won't hyphenate the enclosed word. This is the code:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[applemac]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[hmarginratio=1:1, vmarginratio=1:1, top=32mm,left=30mm, columnsep=20pt]{geometry}

\begin{document}
...
Die auskartierten Aufschlüsse wurden in chronologischer Reihenfolge nach dem Schema 
\textit{A[Aufschlussnummer]} benannt.
...
\end{document}
```

This would be the result:

[image]

Manually hyphenating won't do either:

[image]

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: How about `[Aufschluss-nummer]`?

Comment: This is what I meant by manually hyphenating. The result to this is shown in the second image.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that `A[Aufschlussnummer]` is considered as a single entity with respect to hyphenation and the `[` blocks any other hyphen past it.

The obvious workaround is to add a space between `A` and the bracket. If you don't want it, then a different strategy is needed: define

```
\newcommand{\scheme}[2]{\textit{#1\nolinebreak\hspace{0pt}[#2]}}
```

and input

```
Die auskartierten Aufschlüsse wurden in chronologischer Reihenfolge 
nach dem Schema \scheme{A}{Aufschlussnummer} benannt.
```

[image]

Here `\nolinebreak` is necessary for avoiding a line break between “A” and “[”.